Shading area between tangent normal and x-axis
I was wondering if I could get some help filling in the area bounded between the tangent the normal and the x-axis (which is the triangle). I've read through quite a bit of material and threads but cannot manage to find out how to do it with the way I have currently set up my graphs.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (3,{0.06*exp(3)+1}) circle[radius=2pt] node[right] {$(a,f(a))$};
    \fill (3,{0.06*exp(3)+1}) circle[radius=2pt];
    \draw [<->] (-1,0) -- (7,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw [<->] (0,-1) -- (0,5)node[above]{$y$};
    \draw[domain=-1:4] [<->] plot (\x,{0.06*exp(\x)+1}) node[right] {$y = f(x)$};
    \draw[domain=0.5:4] [<->] plot (\x, {0.06*exp(3)*(\x-3)+0.06*exp(3)+1}) node[right] {$\ell_T$};

    \draw[domain=2:6.5] [<->] plot (\x, {-1/(0.06*exp(3))*(\x-3)+0.06*exp(3)+1}) node[right] {$\ell_N$};;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center} 

\end{document}

This is what it looks like so far.


Welcome to TeX.SE!

Please always extend your code to a full compilable small document.

You can make use of the intersections library (and also let TikZ calculate the position of (a, f(a)) on its own):
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, backgrounds}
 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw[<->, name path=x-axis] (-1,0) -- (7,0) 
        node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[<->] (0,-1) -- (0,5) 
        node[above]{$y$};
    \draw[domain=-1:4, <->] 
        plot (\x,{0.06*exp(\x)+1}) 
        node[right] {$y = f(x)$};
    \draw[domain=0.5:4, <->, name path=tangent] 
        plot (\x, {0.06*exp(3)*(\x-3)+0.06*exp(3)+1}) 
        node[right] {$\ell_T$};
    \draw[domain=2:6.5, <->, name path=normal] 
        plot (\x, {-1/(0.06*exp(3))*(\x-3)+0.06*exp(3)+1}) 
        node[right] {$\ell_N$};

    \path[name intersections={of=normal and tangent}]
        (intersection-1) coordinate (a);
    \path[name intersections={of=normal and x-axis}]
        (intersection-1) coordinate (b);
    \path[name intersections={of=tangent and x-axis}]
        (intersection-1) coordinate (c);
        
    \filldraw (a) circle[radius=2pt] 
        node[right] {$(a,f(a))$};

    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \fill[red!10] (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

You could also make use of the fillbetween library that comes with the pgfplots package (maybe a bit overkill here, but useful in more complicated settings where one boundary is a plot for example):
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{fillbetween, backgrounds}
 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw (3,{0.06*exp(3)+1}) circle[radius=2pt] 
        node[right] {$(a,f(a))$};
    \fill (3,{0.06*exp(3)+1}) circle[radius=2pt];
    \draw[<->, name path=x-axis] (-1,0) -- (7,0) 
        node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[<->] (0,-1) -- (0,5) 
        node[above]{$y$};
    \draw[domain=-1:4, <->] 
        plot (\x,{0.06*exp(\x)+1}) 
        node[right] {$y = f(x)$};
    \draw[domain=0.5:4, <->, name path=tangent] 
        plot (\x, {0.06*exp(3)*(\x-3)+0.06*exp(3)+1}) 
        node[right] {$\ell_T$};
    \draw[domain=2:6.5, <->, name path=normal] 
        plot (\x, {-1/(0.06*exp(3))*(\x-3)+0.06*exp(3)+1}) 
        node[right] {$\ell_N$};

    \path[
        name path=temp,
        intersection segments={
            of=normal and tangent,
            sequence={L2 -- R1}
        }
    ] -- cycle;

    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \fill[
            red!10,
            intersection segments={
                of=temp and x-axis,
                sequence={L1 -- R2}
            }
        ] -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Both result in the the same output:

